# How to run Tibco InConcert Batch registry script from Tibco BusinessWorks 5

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

We have old application that using Tibco InConcert server. We want to Integrate the application with Tibco BW5. 
I have really limited knowledge of Tibco InConcert and TIBCO BusinessWorks Collaborator. Looks like it's pretty old software that not supported by Tibco anymore.

The question is how I can run Tibco InConcert Batch registry script from Tibco BW5?
the exact script that I need to run:

```
create user <name> address <email> with pool;
```

[image]

The script is required for adding users to InConsert server. the end goal is to add InConcert users from BW5 process.

After installing TIBCO BusinessWorks Collaborator 5.2.0 I see that 2 additional paletes where added to TibcoDesigner: Collaborator Client and Collaborator Design.

I see activity for Query inConsert Users but I don't see activity for Adding users
[image]

The end goal is to add InConcert users directly from BW5 process.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally integrated InConcert Batch Registry tool through command line tibco activity. It may be not really elegant solution and also require the tibco services run from the server where batreg.exe installed but works fine.

[image]

From InConcert Batch Registry documentation:

> **Batch Mode on Windows**
>
> The syntax to start the Windows Batch Registry in batch mode is:

```
ic_home\bin\batreg.exe [-icclient client_data ] [-ictimeout interval ] input_file [ output_file ]
```

> For example, to start a batch script that adds new users for user icdba on server tibicsvr, enter:
>
> ```
> ic_home\bin\batreg.exe -icclient icdba/icdba@tibicsvr addusers.btg
> ```
>
> **Batch mode on UNIX**
>
> The syntax to start the UNIX Batch Registry in batch mode is:

```
IcBatchRegistry [-icclient client_data ] [ -ictimeout interval ] \ input_file [ output_file ]
```

> For example, to start a batch script that adds new users for user icdba on server tibicsvr, enter:

```
IcBatchRegistry -icclient icdba/icdba@tibicsvr addusers.btg
```

> On UNIX, you can also specify client
>    data in a text file. The client data should be the only content in the
>    file. To specify this file with the -icclient switch, precede the file
>    name with a colon:

```
 IcBatchRegistry -icclient :login_info.txt addusers.btg
```